# try/catch in throws function

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throws

If I put a try/catch in a throws function, in case of an exception which one runs?

1. Does it do whatever in catch clause, throws an exception or both?
2. Adding some more details, what if the exception in the inner scope
   is inherited form the other or vice versa?
3. What does this function when post doesn't include a parameter?

Example :

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException{
        int number;
    try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(getParameter(req,"number"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
    number = 5;
        }
    }
```

where getParameter is a function in my BaseServlet class which extends HttpServlet:

```
protected String getParameter(HttpServletRequest req, String parameter)
    throws ServletException {
    String value = req.getParameter(parameter);
    if (isEmptyOrNull(value)) 
        throw new ServletException("Parameter " + parameter + " not found");

    return value.trim();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "which one runs"? Which do you think? Couldn't you just try it?

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: I can't understand your last two questions.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Several people answered exactly what I wonder in several minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to both **handle the exception (using try/catch) and duck the exception(using throws clause)**, compiler chooses to **handle the exception**.
In your case, it will **catch** the **exception** and assign `5` to `number`.

### And a Suggestion:

its a bad practice to handle all exceptions inside a single catch block, i.e.,

```
catch(Exception e)
```

always catch most Specific exceptions.

Comment: You probably mean - `catch specific` exception in the last line.

Comment: @RohitJain yepp, thats exactly what i meant, i will edit it to correct the **Terminology** :P

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, spot on.

Answer (score 1):

The catch clause will handle any `Exception` thrown in the body of the try block, effectively rendering the `throws` declaration pointless.

In other words, if the call to `getParameter` throws a `ServletException`, `number` will be set to 5 and no exception will be thrown beyond the body of that try-catch statement.

Comment: You mean it runs inner catch clause and ignore outer throws?

Comment: Yes. Anything caught in a try-catch statement is not "re-thrown" to the outer `throws` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`getParameter()` will throw ServletException.
The catch clause in `post(..)` will handle any Exception thrown in the body of the try block

It will execute the line:

```
number = 5;
```

but i don't see what you do with number...

I will also sugest that you refactor it to:

```
catch (ServletException e) {
    number = 5;
}
```

Only catch the exception that you are expecting...

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what's written there:

1. `getParameter()` will throw `ServletException`
2. This exception will escape from `getParameter()`
3. Inside `try`/`catch` in `doPost()` it will be caught
4. `catch` block will handle it by calling `number = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You are chatching all Exceptions,
so if everything ok. number gets the value from parseInt().

If that will throw any Exception (usually NumberFormatException, or your ServeletException) then you 
reach the Exception causem and get

**the value 5**

Answer (score 0):

Your try-catch block will always run, unless a Throwable is provoked by your try block.